# Операторы 'NULL' и 'NOT NULL'

Tags: база-данных

Сколько бы не читал, до меня не доходят эти 2 оператора. Нельзя ли просто оставить пустыми? В чем разница, я дописал их, не дописал? Жду помощи. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Просто null значит нет инициализации.
Нельзя по умолчанию считать какое значение должно быть у переменной.

Простой целочисленный тип например INT можно по умолчанию считать нулем.

> int i;
>
> y = i + 5; // здесь допустим y будет
> 5.
>
> Строка STRING по умолчанию может
> считаться пустой.

Допустим есть поле возраст. В нём хранится от 0 до 130.

Пользователи которые уже ввели свой возраст имеют от 0 до 50.
Если по умолчанию считать эти поля равными 0. То тогда при поиске мы получим что младенцев на сайте у которых возраст 0 больше половины.

А вот если эти поля не инициализированы, тогда можно добавить проверку NOT NULL и все кто не ввёл возраст выпадут из поиска.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда надо обязательно инициализировать переменные.Эту задачу и выполняет null

Comment: И всё-таки для обязательной инициализации поля используется [NOT NULL][1] constraint.


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp